# Firebase SMS Invites

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-invites

I am Using Firebase for integrating App Invitation for Android. I am using SMS only invites. I have been through the firebase docs, and haven't find any method to get mobile nos. of the people whom I have Invited and the invitation has been successfully sent to them. I can only see this:

```
public static String[] getInvitationIds (int resultCode, Intent result)
```

method only in the docs.How can I get the numbers of people who have recieved the invite.

Comment: How to enforce SMS only invites? I wasn't able to find this... Could you please help me out here?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. This is intentional, as the user hasn't necessarily agreed to share their contacts' phone numbers with you.

Comment: How can i disable SMS invites? It may charge them accidentally.